# Chrome Extension: how to safely restrict the content and customise the user experience?

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, azure-active-directory

I'm enjoying developing cross-browser web extensions, the main target being Chrome, so much that I started to think to develop one for my company. I find a chrome extension quite a cheap and efficient way to deploy internal apps. The main purpose is to host a couple of dynamic dashboards that fetch data from various APIs by using cross-domain ajax in background scripts. I finalized the app and I was also able to implement the authentication via chrome.identity and Azure AD.
However, I am struggling to find a safe way to customise the content.

I mean, when the extension is installed it requires to login to azure via the chrome.identity flow. Then I get a token that I use to query ms graph and get the user ID, name, email and basic info.
Until I get this information I want the browser action (popup) to be unavailable to the user as well as any other extension pages. After a successful login I would like to show the content on the pop up and to let the user access the pages, but here I want to customize the experience.

I know how to use the user id retrieved from the api call to customize the extension, but I think it is not safe because all the code is in the client.

If I code something like

```
if (user === logged) show something
```

it will be damn easy for a malicious user to look at the code and bypass it, or even to impersonate another user. And chrome extension cannot be obfuscated.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Any client-side JS code can be inspected and circumvented.

Comment: That is clear. I am wondering how apps like Grammarly or other professional one's can display a different content or enable some features based on the type of user without risking that the user compromise it on the client. I mean how to avoid that the user pretends to be logged in. Oauth2 at the end of the day can authorize or not. Then if your business logic depends on the user id that must be implemented locally on the client and so can be exploited. Isn't it?

Comment: Why do you think they're using a safe method?

Comment: I'm not saying they are not safe...I'm saying I'm wondering how they achieve this. On the server is easy, when you get the current user id you can show/hide pages and modules. But with extensions all your if/else logic is on the client. Therefore something like ```if (user === "MIKE") {}``` can be easily exploited and you can circumvent the actual user retrieved via ajax....so how can you achieve that safely?

Comment: They only way is to move parts of UI/logic to a server with authentication so the client stores a temporary token like a cookie on a normal site. This is the standard web model, I'd say.

Comment: I totally understand the token part. Even in spa, when you have a valid token, you can start fetching data from a service. However, at some point, you will want to get a user-object that tells you that, for example, a specific component must be rendered. This is where I do not understand security. If the user-objects has a prop, for instance, ```{ showAdminBar : false }``` isn't easy to be changed client-side to "true"? :/

Comment: My point is that you need to generate/render the html/UI (or parts of it) on a server.

Comment: Ah here we go. But this totally conflicts with the spa architecture. With spa you download the HTML only once and then you execute all your logic within the client. Injecting arbitrary html via ajax is even less secure honestly.

Comment: This is similar to server-side rendering, which is used by lots of web apps, it's not less secure. Anyway, there's conceptually no way to do anything meaningful on a client-side JS "safely".

Comment: _And chrome extension cannot be obfuscated._ Why do you think so? Eventually any chrome extension is just a set of HTML and JS files which can be obfuscated in the same way as usual JS.

Comment: Technically they can of course. But they will not pass Google's review if obfuscated.